# Are Hsp70 proteins only activated in response to heat shock?

Tags: botany, proteins, plant-physiology, plant-anatomy, plant-perception

Hsp70 proteins are chaperones that assist in protein folding in my plant physiology textbook it says the Hsp70 proteins were discovered by inducing heat shock. But do they only work in response to heat shock stress?

I know these types of proteins are found in many organisms but I am interested in how they assist on protein folding or stress response in plants specifically.

Comment: The wikipedia Hsp70 article answers the headline question.

Comment: They get upregulated under stress, but will be expressed normally. In effect the name is deceptive...